# Truncate string with realloc() in C?

Tags: c, string, realloc

For an assignment i´m asked to change a string `str3` containing "Hello World!" to "Hello", and to use `realloc()` to remove the the exess memory. I dont realy know how to do it.

1. How do i use `realloc()` to truncate the string?
2. How do i change the string from "Hello World!" to "Hello"?

The `DString` is a `char*` pointer so `DString *str` is a double pointer `char**`.
From the `main()`function we send `str3` containing "Hello World!" and a blanc space to the function `shrinkDString()`.

```
int main() {
    shrinkDString(&str3, ' ');  // truncate str3 after the blank, only "Hello" remains
    shrinkDString(&str3, ' ');  // nothing happens, "Hello" remains the same
}
```

As pre- and postcondition i´m supposed to use `assert()`. The `DString *str` is a double pointer to `str3` and `ch` is a blanc space. Storing "hello World!" in `str3` uses 13 memory including `\0`, "Hello" should only use memory of 6 including `\0`.

```
void shrinkDString(DString *str, char ch) {
   // Shrinks the DString *str up to the first occurence of ch.
   // Precondition: str is not NULL
   // Precondition: *str is not NULL
   /* Postcondition: if str has been truncated, its new length corresponds to the position of ch in the 
      original str*/

   /* Tips:
      - think that str is already allocated in memory and may be changed! Only the proper amount of 
        memory for storing the truncated string is allocated when the function return
      - do not forget the char for ending a string '\0'
      - useful C functions: realloc.
   */
}
```

This is what i´ve tried so far but i get a memory leak when using `realloc()` and `assert(*str != NULL);` is dereferencing `NULL` pointer.

```
void shrinkDString(DString *str, char ch) {

    assert(str != NULL);
    assert(*str != NULL);
   
    *str = (char*)realloc(*str, 6);
}
```

I dont know how to continue. Grateful for any help!

Comment: Axel Foolya, curious, why code with the cast `(char*)` in `*str = (char*)realloc(*str, 6);` versus just using `*str = realloc(*str, 6);`?

Answer (score 2):

You'd do something like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
  {
  char *s = malloc(100);

  strcpy(s, "Hello World!");
  
  printf("1 - s=%p  *s = '%s'\n", s, s);
  
  s[5] = '\0';
  
  s = realloc(s, strlen(s)+1);
  
  printf("2 - s=%p  *s = '%s'\n", s, s);

  return 0;
  }
```

Note that `realloc` may not actually change the address of the memory block - it may just release the extra space at the end of it, or it may not do anything at all!

Note that this example code doesn't do any of the necessary checking for invalid return values, etc, which you should add.

[onlinegdb here](https://onlinegdb.com/HyRaEy44D)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible only using the realloc. You need also to add the trailing null character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TEXT "Hello World"

int main()
{
    char *ptr = malloc(strlen(TEXT) + 1);

    strcpy(ptr,TEXT);
    printf("original string: %s", ptr);

    ptr = realloc(ptr, 6);
    ptr[5] = 0;
    printf("realloced string: %s", ptr);
    free(ptr);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: is there any reason why valgrind might flag the `ptr[5] = 0;` line with `Invalid read of size 1`?

Answer (score 0):

> How do i use `realloc()` to truncate the string?

You don't. A string is terminated by a null byte, and `realloc()` does not change any of the string's bytes. At least not in any way that you could rely on. The entire effect of a shrinking `realloc()` is, that it will consider the memory beyond the new size as free and safe for reuse by a future `malloc()` call. So, for example, the code

```
char* string1 = strdup("Hello World!");
string1 = realloc(string1, 6);
char* string2 = malloc(7);
printf("%s", string2);   //reading uninitialized data, don't do this
```

**might** conceivably print "World!". It could print "I've encrypted your harddrive, please pay ***$ in bitcoins..." instead. Whatever. The C standard does not care. It is simply one of the possible things that might happen, that the `malloc()` call returns the memory that was cut off from `string1` with the `realloc()` call. (Real implementations won't actually print "World!" for reasons which are way beyond this question.)

---

> How do i change the string from "Hello World!" to "Hello"?

You terminate the string with a null byte. That's as simple as

```
(*str)[5] = 0;
```

Note the parentheses which force the double pointer to be dereferenced before performing the array subscript operation. Once you have cut down the string like this, you can subsequently also shrink the allocation with `realloc()`:

```
(*str)[5] = 0;
*str = realloc(*str, 6);   //5 characters plus one terminating null byte
```

Answer (score -1):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. checks for and handles errors

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void shrinkDString( char **str, char targetChar) 
{
    char *localStr = *str;
    
    assert(str != NULL);
    assert(localStr != NULL);

   
    char *stopChar = strchr( localStr, (int)targetChar );
    if( ! stopChar )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "target char not in  **str\n" );
        return;
    }
    
    // impllied else, target char found
    
    *stopChar = '\0';
    
    char *temp = realloc( localStr, strlen( localStr ) + 1 );
    if( ! temp )
    {
        perror( "realloc failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    
    // implied else, realloc successful
    *str = temp;
}
```

Comment: Love functions which terminate the program when something goes wrong. Very bad practice.

Comment: What is the cast in the srtchr for?

Comment: Why strchr and again strlen? There is no point. Think to avoid it.

Comment: @P__J__, the cast to `strchr()` is due to the second parameter expected to be an `int`, not a `char`.  Although auto promotion will handle it without a cast.

Comment: Cast is not needed at all. And it is dangerous if you by mistake pass pointer for example

Comment: @P__J__, why the use of `strlen()`?  because the number of char in the 'shortened' string is unknown and the call to `realloc()` needs to know the number of char to allocate

Comment: It can be calculated very easy without the strlen. You do not have to parse string twice

Comment: @P__J__,  sure, we can do a subtraction of the two pointers, but the OP is obviously a beginner in C (I.E. a student) and there are several restrictions about math operations with pointers, so rather than mislead the OP, I used the call to `strlen()` which returns a `size_t`, which is what the call to `realloc()` expects

Comment: subtraction of two pinters gives good integer type `realloc`. size_t explanation does not make any sense here

Comment: @P__J__,  I thought you were a 'old hand' at programming in C.  I guess not, if you cannot tell the difference between the two calls to `assert()`

Comment: @P__J__, when an unrecoverable error occurs, there is no reason to continue the program

Comment: The program should decide - not helper funcvtion

Comment: @P__J__,  how is the calling program to know an unrecoverable error occurred?  It doesn't.  So the 'helper' function should handle the problem